# What is the meaning of "trap" in relation to integer underflow/overflow?

Tags: integer, integer-overflow, motoko, internet-computer

Reading through the docs for Internet Computer's Motoko:

https://sdk.dfinity.org/docs/languages/motoko-at-a-glance.html#_bounded_numbers_trapping

I realised I don't have a good model for what the word "trapping" means here:

> Bounded numbers (trapping) Nat8, Nat16, Nat32, Nat64, Int8, Int16,
> Int32, Int64
>
> trap on over- and underflow
>
> need type annotations specified
>
> literals: 13, 0xf4, -20, 1_000_000

Does it mean that the integer will stay fixed at the maximum/minimum if an attempt to write a number that would cause an overflow/underflow?

**What is the origin of the word "trap" in this context? And what is its precise meaning here?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A trap in this context causes the execution to abort.  The canister will still be fine but the call being made to the canister will fail.  See [this part of the manual.](https://smartcontracts.org/docs/language-guide/basic-concepts.html#overview-traps)

As a demo, I set up a counter canister with type Nat8 from [one of these templates](https://github.com/MioQuispe/create-ic-app), so it should support values 0..255 inclusive, and initialized it to 250:

```
$ cat counter-canister/main.mo 
actor {
    stable var currentValue: Nat8 = 250;

    public func increment(): async () {
        currentValue += 1;
    };

    public query func getValue(): async Nat8 {
        currentValue;
    };
};
```

I then clicked the "increment" button.  It increased from 250 until 255 as expected, then on the next click, this showed up in the browser console:

```
vendor.e49a5b15.js:831 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Call was rejected:
  Request ID: 0f549a49b80b31831e423196d086e36c12df51896ffaaa59e99bae7fa66047aa
  Reject code: 5
  Reject text: Canister ryjl3-tyaaa-aaaaa-aaaba-cai trapped explicitly: arithmetic overflow

    at pollForResponse (vendor.e49a5b15.js:831)
    at async n (vendor.e49a5b15.js:838)
    at async HTMLButtonElement.n (index.4a11dcea.js:5)
```

Reloading the page showed that the value was still at the maximum, 255.

The canister is still perfectly functional.  If I had bothered to put a decrement button there as well I could have counted down a bit and then increased the value until I hit the limit again.